# Headers for Excel worksheet using EPPlus

Tags: vb.net, excel, epplus, vba

I am using EPPLus to create and format an excel sheet from my data set. I want to set headers on the excel sheet using EPPlus. I could not find a way to do it. I want to set the left header, right header and center header.
I have done this using VBA code, but I wan to move away from that.
In VBA I would just do

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.LeftHeader = ""
.RightHeader =""
.CenterHeader= ""
End With
```

Help!!
Thanks

PS: I am creating a winforms application. I was not sure if that would change anything but just wanted to mention it here. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

```
It can be done using 
workSheet.HeaderFooter.FirstHeader.LeftAlignedText = ""
workSheet.HeaderFooter.FirstHeader.RightAlignedText = ""
workSheet.HeaderFooter.FirstHeader.CenterAlignedText = ""
```

This sets for the First page.
Changing the `FirstHeader` Property to `EvenHeader` and `OddHeader` sets if for the following pages.

There are a couple of properties `differentFirst` and `differentOddEven` which set if the pages have different headers. But I was not able to get it to work By setting them to false and just setting one of the headers.
Had to set all three separately.

Hope it is useful
Thanks