# How to get the row number of the last row when you are printing an excel sheet (EPPlus)

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to add one picture (displaying "DRAFT") by printable Excel worksheet in C# EPPlus.

I need to know if there is a way to find the last visible row of each page of a worksheet when you are printing it. I can't pretend that it will always be a fix number of row per page because it depends on the content of the cells.

Here is my current code that use a fix number of row per page (30) to insert image. This result in approximately one image per printable page except that in each new page the image is not at the same place. (Slightly off, depending on content of cells.)

```
public void InsertDraftImage(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, FileInfo draft_image)
{

    int maxRowNumber = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
    int rowByPage = 30;
    int numberOfPage = (maxRowNumber / rowByPage) + 1;


    ExcelPicture picture = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPage; i++)
    {
        if(draft_image != null)
        {
            picture = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture(i.ToString(), draft_image);
            picture.SetSize(609, 545); //original image size
            picture.SetPosition(i * rowByPage, 0, 1, 0); 
            picture.EditAs = eEditAs.Absolute;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about putting this as footer so it appears automatically at bottom of every page? [Related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14524378/4879022)

Comment: I want to add a picture that cover a large area across each page so that the user knows not to use the data because of the big picture "Draft". I don't know if a footer really can do what I want?

Comment: You mean watermark on the whole page?

Comment: Yes, like a watermark, but for each printable page

Comment: [Duplicate of this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885373/adding-excel-watermark-using-officeopenxml-epplus)

Comment: Yeah before writing my question I saw that post but didn't make it work in code EPPlus. Before trying for too many hours, I write down my question to know if anybody can tell me a solution regarding my tactic with the row per page so I can make it work with my picture :)

Comment: Nice try so far. Not sure if this will work but you can try getting the ranges for print area and then draw the image, check [this link](https://github.com/ylatuya/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelPrinterSettings.cs)  and [this](http://atakala.com/browser/Item.aspx?user_id=amos&dict_id=2363) on sample to get the reference for print area and you might be able to get some pointer to achieve what you are looking out for.

Comment: Does the user have the ability to edit the content before printing?  If yes, then I think you only solutions would be VBA.  Epplus cannot really predict what will happen to the data after it create the excel file.  VBA means creating an XLSM which might have security concerns depending on your environment.  But if you can then you can have EPPlus add the VBA code that will fire when the user goes to print.

Comment: @Ernie No the user can't edit the content before printing.

I'm currently trying out the footer solution. I have only one thing missing that I can't find: The 'Scale with document' boolean that you can check/uncheck in Page Setup when you are printing. I think that if I find how to set it in EPPlus this would be the solution :)

Comment: @pikarie  Cool.  If that option is not avilable to you in EPPlus you can probably set it with XML fairly easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to implement the missing code in 'ExcelHeaderFooter.cs' from the EPPlus with a workmate without success, we finally did it by following Ernie suggestion!!

There is my final code to insert a picture into each page of a printable excel file generate with EPPlus in C#.

It is done by adding the picture in the footer and setting the Boolean ScaleWithDoc to false (default = true).

```
public void InsertDraftImage(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, FileInfo draft_image)
{
    ExcelHeaderFooterText footer = worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter; //all page have same footer
    footer.InsertPicture(draft_image, PictureAlignment.Centered);
}
```

Added this code in my method to create the ExcelWorksheet (all the other excel style, populate, settings).

```
XmlAttribute temp = worksheet.WorksheetXml.CreateAttribute("scaleWithDoc");
temp.Value = "0";
worksheet.WorksheetXml.GetElementsByTagName("headerFooter")[0].Attributes.Append(temp);

package.Save();
```